# Remove nginx .htpasswd for only single page

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have an angular web application deployed on the Nginx server.
and I have added Nginx .htpasswd for my website so that the website is password protected.
Now I have to disable it for a single page not for whole website.
for instance, I have to disable it for the welcome page.
is there any way to do that.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Hi, @VishwasNaharI have to disable the password protected functionality for one page so that user can see that page but when they are navigating to another page they should ask for credentials.